# Android EditText string returns to ""

Tags: android, double, android-edittext

I'm struggling to work with the input of an EditText in my android app. I'm entering decimal values, and I've tackled the decimal point already, however my app is crashing when I remove all of the contents of the EditText. I have in my onTextChanged function for the EditText widget a check for values of NULL or "", however this is being surpassed. Here are my relevant functions:

```
private void initializeEditTextListener(){
    final TextView resultView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultView);
    final EditText userInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.haveTextField);
    userInput.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            String inputString = userInput.getText().toString();
            if(inputString != null && inputString != "")
            {
                double input = Double.parseDouble(inputString); //<-line causing error
                double result = input * getFactorFromTable();   //specified in logcat
                resultView.setText(Double.toString(result));
            }
            else
            {
                resultView.setText("");
            }
        }
    }
    );
}
```

My logcat:

> 10-19 17:53:59.313  16225-16225/khandy.application.convertible E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
>               at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
>               at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:248)
>               at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)
>               at khandy.application.convertible.EntryActivity$1.onTextChanged(EntryActivity.java:237)
>               at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7405)
>               at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:7467)
>               at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:9218)
>               at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:962)
>               at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:496)
>               at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.delete(SpannableStringBuilder.java:212)
>               at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.delete(SpannableStringBuilder.java:30)
>               at android.text.method.BaseKeyListener.backspaceOrForwardDelete(BaseKeyListener.java:94)
>               at android.text.method.BaseKeyListener.backspace(BaseKeyListener.java:49)
>               at android.text.method.BaseKeyListener.onKeyDown(BaseKeyListener.java:155)
>               at android.text.method.NumberKeyListener.onKeyDown(NumberKeyListener.java:138)
>               at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:5544)
>               at android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:5356)
>               at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2705)
>               at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:7205)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1363)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1363)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1363)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1363)
>               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2083)
>               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1459)
>               at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2416)
>               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2010)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRootImpl.java:3894)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3828)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3385)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4483)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4461)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3146)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

What concerns me is that I'm being told the invalid double is "", however I am checking for such an event...

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String inputString = userInput.getText().toString();
```

This is not the preferred way to get text from `EditText` inside `onTextChanged`.
Your `onTextChanged` function should be like this

```
@Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            String inputString = s.toString();
            if(inputString != null && inputString != "")
            {
                double input = Double.parseDouble(inputString); //<-line causing error
                double result = input * getFactorFromTable();   //specified in logcat
                resultView.setText(Double.toString(result));
            }
            else
            {
                resultView.setText("");
            }
        }
```

In `onTextChanged` function `CharSequence s` parameter is nothing but the text from the `EditText`

And you should catch exceptions resulting from null strings and strings containing letters

```
@Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            String inputString = s.toString();
           try
            {
                double input = Double.parseDouble(inputString); //<-line causing error
                double result = input * getFactorFromTable();   //specified in logcat
                resultView.setText(Double.toString(result));
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException e)
            {
                resultView.setText("");
            }


           catch(Exception e)
           {
                resultView.setText("");
           }
  }
```

Comment: Awesome! The exception route makes much more sense. This will cover many more cases than me checking explicitly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
inputString != ""
```

should be

```
!inputString.equals("")
```

When you are compraing numbers or boolean, you can do the comparison you did. But when using `String` you need the `equals` to compare strings.

Comment: That solves it! Like getting a B+ on a math test, it's always the little things...

Answer (score 1):

**For ease create a method to check wether a String is Null or Empty**

Create a utility class(Say **AppUtility**.java),and define a method. So now you can use this method any where in your programme.

```
public class AppUtility{

public static boolean isStringEmpty(String input){
        if(input != null && input.length() == 0){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**And check the condition like that**

```
String inputString = userInput.getText().toString();
            if(AppUtility.isStringEmpty(inputString)){
            // Do YOUR WORK
    }
```

Hope this will help you.